# What is being shown on these two seismometer images from Insight?

Tags: insight, seismology

I'd like to preface this question with the fact that I know very little about seismology. On the Insight page with [the most recently taken photos](https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/multimedia/images/), I found two images with data on them, and very little accompanying explanation of what I'm looking at.

[image]

Can somebody explain what the **MS Paint looking spray-painted area** actually is in this image?

[image]

Also, I'd like a little bit of clarification on what this image is showing us as well<s>, I understand this is the spectrogram of the first vibrations detected on Mars</s>. The device hasn't been deployed yet according to the answers. Can somebody put a frame of reference around this for me?